# How do I skip a specific overlay on a beamer slide

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have a slide with many overlays. Shortly before the talk I notice that I need to save some time, and I want to remove one overlay from the slide, i.e. go from overlay 3 directly to 5.

Is there a way to do so, besides manually re-numbering all overlay numbers >4?

Comment: (Untested, hence a comment) Try changing the `\begin{frame}` to `\begin{frame}<1-3,5->`.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Tested: Remember where it is and click the right button twice on the small wireless click-thing with a laser pointer :) BTW, if I remember correctly, the "overlays" are called "slides".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specify which overlays are actually rendered by adding an *overlay specification* to the `\begin{frame}` of the frame environment.  For the case described here, putting:

```
\begin{frame}<1-3,5->
```

should work.  That says that beamer should render slides 1 to 3, then from 5 onwards.  (Note that if there is no slide corresponding to 5 then one will be made anyway as this counts as an explicit mention of that slide.)

For more possibilities, see the description of the overlay specifications in the beamer manual.